# Perl Script to split file by number of rows .. add header row to top of each file

Tags: perl, file

I have this perl script (below) which splits 1 data file into multiple by the number of lines in each file. I am trying to adapt this script to write the first row of the first file (header row) to the top of each split file. What is the best way to do this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $source = shift or &usage();
my $lines_per_file = shift or &usage();
my $filename = shift or &usage();
my $target = shift or &usage();
my $filenum = 2;

my $dir = "${target}";
chdir($dir) or die "Failed to cd to $dir: $!";

$filename =~ s{\.[^.]+$}{};

open (my $FH, "<$source") or die "Could not open source file. $!";
open (my $OUT, ">${filename}_1.csv") or die "Could not open destination file. $!";
print "Writing file: ${filename}_1.csv\n";
my $i = 0;

while (<$FH>) {
    print $OUT $_;
    $i++;
    if ($i % $lines_per_file == 0) {
        close($OUT);
        my $FHNEW = ($filenum);
        open ($OUT, ">${filename}_${FHNEW}.csv") or die "Could not open destination file. $!";
            print "Writing file: ${filename}_${filenum}.csv\n";
            $filenum++;
    }
}

sub usage() {
print <<EOF;

    PROGRAM NAME: Split .csv file

    DESCRIPTION:
    Takes a file and creates many small files out of the large file.

    EXAMPLE USAGE: splitfile.pl filename.csv 300000 filename /dir/

        PARAMETERS:
        1. Source File: File name of the source file to partition.
        2. Maximum number of lines per file: The number of lines per file.
        3. Filename without the extension
        4. Target location of split files ending with /

EOF
exit;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what your code is doing? Have you written it yourself?

Comment: The _best way_ would be to _remember_ (i.e. _store_) the first line of the first file in a global variable (outside the `while`) and print that stored line whenever you open a new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@content = <$FH>;
print $content[0];
```

BTW, there are many different ways to do this. you can also use command to print. such  as

```
foreach my $file(glob "$dir.*")
{
   print `head -n 1 $file`;
}
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: I am obviously answering this question --- get the first line of the fine.

Comment: But that isn't the question asked. OP wants to print the first line of one file into each splitted files

Comment: print `head -n 1 $file` means to print the first line of the files, after you got the first line output, it is easy to print it into other files without get the lines from the row number. Don't think it is a good solution? or you don't know how to insert the output at the beginning of other splitted files?